# Convert Java.Security.KeyPair to .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: java, android, cryptography, xamarin, rsa

How can I encode a Java-produced RSA private (and public) key such that it can be decoded in .NET for use within `RSACryptoServiceProvider`?

I have tried this code:

```
var keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.GetInstance("RSA");
keyGen.Initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.GenerateKeyPair();

IPrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.Private;
byte[] nativePrivateKey = privateKey.GetEncoded();

var nativeToRsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
nativeToRsa.ImportCspBlob(nativePrivateKey); // throws a CryptographicException
```

I'm using Xamarin.Android to write C#, but the "native" Java RSA key generator is *much* faster than the mono one. So I want to use the Java one, but I still need to be able to exchange the public and/or private keys with Windows folks to use with `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

So ultimately I may want/need to go both ways (Java<->RSACryptoServiceProvider). Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C# has a load from xml functionm for RSA Crypto Provider. Try the approach below:

JAVA

```
                KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    BigInteger mod_Int = publicKey.getModulus();
    BigInteger exp_Int = publicKey.getPublicExponent();
    byte[] mod_Bytes_Extra = mod_Int.toByteArray();
    byte[] mod_Bytes = new byte[128];
    System.arraycopy(mod_Bytes_Extra, 1, mod_Bytes, 0, 128);
    byte[] exp_Bytes = exp_Int.toByteArray();
    String modulus = Base64.encodeToString(mod_Bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String exponent = Base64.encodeToString(exp_Bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    System.out.println(modulus);
    System.out.println(exponent);
    String public_Xml = "<BitStrength>0124</BitStrength><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>"+modulus+"</Modulus><Exponent>"+exponent+"</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
```

C#

```
class KeyBuilder
    {
        private RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;

        public RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateKey(string rsaKeyPair)
        {
            rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            string xmlString = "<Key>" + rsaKeyPair + "</Key>";
            rsa.FromXmlString(xmlString);
            return rsa;
        }
    }
```

Always make you read/write byte arrays with UTF-8 encoding on java side because Java by default uses Unicode encoding whereas C# uses UTF-8.

Also byte arrays in java are signed whereas in C# they are unsigned. So if you have to parse binary data sent from Java code in C# side read it in a sbyte array.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. The messages encrypted on one and decrypted on the other don't decrypt properly, as if they key is wrong.

Comment: The string you are trying to encrypt and decrypt should be UTF-8 format on both sides. So you read the string into a byte array on java side as a UTF-8 string. This is because java by default uses Unicode as string encoding whereas C# uses UTF-8.

Comment: I'm not transmitting strings at all. I'm transmitting a buffer (byte[] {1,2,3}) to keep things really simple right now. And the buffer comes out completely wrong on the other side right now.

Comment: Also remember byte is by default signed on java side whereas C# byte is unsigned. On C# side read the array into sbyte.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not sure what to do with it however. Whether signed or unsigned, I *hope* that the base64 encoded representation of byte[] (in C# or Java) would be the same. And if not, I'm not sure what I should do instead. sbyte[] isn't what I need, and isn't what Convert.Frombase64string() gives me anyway.

Comment: When you convert base64 to/from byte array make sure in Java you set the encoding as UTF-8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49246/discussion-between-andrew-arnott-and-mobility)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the [PvkConvert.java](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/PvkConvert/) file, which I've rewritten (in the relevant parts) as C# for use in Xamarin.Android apps as [PvkConvert.cs](https://pclcrypto.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/PCLCrypto.Android/PvkConvert.cs).

I learned that `RSACryptoServiceProvider`'s native file format (when you use ExportCspBlob) is called PRIVATEKEYBLOB or PUBLICKEYBLOB (depending on whether the private key is included). Encoding a Java `IPrivateKey` as a PRIVATEKEYBLOB requires a few fields that evidently are only available on an originally generated `IPrivateKey` instance (one deserialized from storage does not cast to the necessary `IRSAPrivateCrtKey` interface.)